# How do I solve the "FROM keyword not found where expected" error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT o.orderid,o.orderdate,
p.productid,o.orderid
o.productstandardprice,
o.productstandardprice*o.ordered_quantity as order_sales_price 
FROM orders_t o and products_t p
WHERE p.productid = o.productid;
```

I have been getting the error  ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected and I'm not sure what to do

Comment: `FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.c = t2.d`

Comment: Also, missing comma at the end of line 2.

Comment: What is this? "FROM orders_t o and products_t p".  Please cite your documentation source that shows using AND in the FROM clause is valid syntax.   When you have an error like the one you reported, the _first_ thing you should do is go to the docs and check your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN properly. `SELECT o.orderid, o.orderdate, p.productid, o.orderid, o.productstandardprice, o.productstandardprice*o.ordered_quantity as order_sales_price  FROM orders_t o join products_t p on p.productid = o.productid;`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `FROM` clause where you should be using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT o.orderid, o.orderdate, p.productid, o.orderid, 
       o.productstandardprice,
       (o.productstandardprice * o.ordered_quantity) as order_sales_price 
FROM orders_t o JOIN
     products_t p
     ON p.productid = o.productid;
```

However, the only column coming from `products_t` is `producctid` -- and that is already in `orders_t`.  I doubt the `JOIN` is intended as a filter, so this should be equivalent:

```
SELECT o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.productid, o.orderid, 
       o.productstandardprice,
       (o.productstandardprice * o.ordered_quantity) as order_sales_price 
FROM orders_t o ;
```

That is, only `orders_t` seems necessary for this query.